# Geometry Nodes, creating UVs from Volume to mesh results in grey UV map

Tags: animation, uv, geometry-nodes, procedural, texture-coordinates

I am trying to create a procedural UV map from the result of a morph between two objects. The resulting mesh is being calculated and then put into a volume cube --> Volume to mesh node. I would like to create procedural UVs for said resulting mesh, but this isn't working.

The morph is taken straight from a yt tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ubfb2K6mL0

Here is the file: [image]

Comment: I don't think this can be done. A UV map is a 2D representation of the vertexes of the 3D mesh. Add or remove a vertex and you get a different UV map. You can use _Object coordinates_ in the shader editor to make it a bit predictable.